# Error while trying to build a .whl file using python setup.py install --static-link with cygwin

Tags: python, pip, cygwin, pyaudio, portaudio

[image]I was trying to build a .whl file using python setup.py install --static-link using cygwin but this error appears: **error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120**

The files i was trying to build were from here : https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio

I followed the same exact commands using cygwin but i wasn't able to do python setup.py install --static-link.Also the same thing occured weirdly enough when i tried to pip install pyaudio.So i did pipwin install pyaudio and it solved my problems in that moment.But now the error remains with a different command.
Anyone know what could be the issue?Thanks

Comment: are you mixing Visual Studio and Cygwin for compilation ? Very unlikely to work.

Comment: @matzeri It can work, I have and do do it. But you have to know what you're doing. This appears to be unintentional.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? It appears likely you're running a native Windows python and not the Cygwin python. Is that what you wanted to do? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry.I do not understand how to use it.I was just trying to install this version of pyaudio:https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio.But since i never used cygwin i don't know how to do it.I'm using python 3.7 because 3.8 is not supported yet.If you could help me with that it would mean a lot to me because i'm a intern in my company but i'm the only programmer and i don't have anyone to help me to finish my application.

Comment: The output of which python is /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python